# How can I turn a string into a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[FIDDle!](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/V8yRw/1/) How can I run my script stored in html? I dont want to take it out of the function...

HTML:

```
<script type="hbrData">
function(){
    var x = 22;
    alert('hi');
}
</script>
```

JS:

```
var script = $('script[type="hbrData"]').text();

$('body').append(script);

script();                  // Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function
```

Comment: Why are you storing it like this?

Comment: You can `eval` it, but what's this for?

Comment: Well, if you want the story, I am going to put data for my handlebars templates where they are going to appear on the page.

Comment: There are way better ways of doing it: look into jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a good reason to do this, use `eval`:

```
var script = $('script[type="hbrData"]').text();

eval('(' + script + ')')();
```

Comment: @sherlock - "_only if you have a good reason_" Are you sure you do?

Answer (score 1):

Give your function in html a function name and you can call it from javascript:

**HTML**

```
<script>
function HelloWorld() {
    var x = 22;
    alert('hi');
}
</script>
```

**Javascript**

```
HelloWorld();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JPsXR/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$.globalEval("("+script+")()");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

HTML:

```
<script type="hbrData">
    var x = 22;
    alert('hi');
</script>
```

JS:

```
var script = $('script[type="hbrData"]').text();
var fn = new Function (script) ;
fn() ;
```

That would avoid the `eval`.

Note that I've changed the HTML from an anonymous function definition to just a two line script.  Don't know whether you're willing to do that.

Comment: The Function constructor is kind of a form of 'eval'